# Providing only some types for generic type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to know if there is a shorthand for specifying only some optional types for generic types in typescript. For example if I have a class with optional types:

```
class GenericClass<A extends Type1 = Type1, B extends Type2 = Type2, C extends Type3 = Type3>
```

Then I'd like to define a subclass such as: `class Subclass extends GenericClass<TypeB>` , which would be a shorthand for `class Subclass extends GenericClass<Type1, TypeB, Type3>`, but it doesn't work. Instead it tries to infer `TypeB` as a subtype of `Type1` which gives an error. It is also allowed in this example, however, to leave out `Type3` and let typescript infer it. Something like this would be useful for me in defining generic react components, where I want to specify the type of state, but not the props.

So am I correct that all preceding optional types must be provided when specifying an optional type. Or is there a way to do as I am trying?

For optional function arguments you can just specify `undefined` for the preceding optionals, this doesn't work for generics but I did try, using `void` instead but that also didn't work. I also tried using a syntax like `Subclass extends GenericClass<B = TypeB>` but that also doesn't work.

I've seen some suggestions for replacing optional function arguments with an interface, like:

```
interface Args { a?: number, b?: string, c?: any}
function myFunc(Args) {}
```

which can then be called like `myFunc({b: "value"});` and avoids having to do `myFunc(undefined, "value");`. This feels like a poor alternative, but maybe it is possible to do something like this for generic types? I'm not sure what that would look like though.

another thing I tried is overloading the type like `type GenericClass<B extends Type2> = GenericClass<Type1, B, Type3>`. This doesn't work, unless I type it with a different name, like `GenericClassB`

Comment: You're either looking for *partial type argument inference* with some sort of sigil like `GenericClass<*, TypeB, *>` as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) or *named type arguments* like `GenericClass<B=TypeB>` as requested in [ms/TS#38913](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38913); neither are part of the language. Your workarounds are the available workarounds I know of.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, hopefully one of these options will be added to the language soon. If you are able, maybe also comment on the idea of the interface-like workaround I speculated about in my question (i.e. `myFunc({b: "value"});` for functions). I'm not sure I would wan't to use this in my code but I'm curious if something like this would work for type arguments.

Comment: It won't work without something like [ms/TS#20126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126) which was never merged into the language; maybe ms/TS#38913 or a more recent variant at ms/TS#54254 will eventually be implemented, but for now there's nothing wonderful.  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't currently have the feature you're looking for, at least as of TS5.1.  [Generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments can only be omitted if they have [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) and you are not allowed to skip any. There are a few open feature requests which, if implemented, would probably do what you want:

- There's *partial type argument inference* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  Part of that proposal would be to allow a "sigil" or "placeholder" type so you could write something like `GenericClass<*, TypeB, *>` or `GenericClass<_, TypeB, _>` or the like.
- There's also *named type arguments* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#38913](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38913), where you could write `GenericClass<B=TypeB>`, or as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#54254](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54254) where you could write something like `GenericClass<B: TypeB>` or maybe `GenericClass<{B: TypeB}>`.
- Finally, the workaround you mention whereby you use a single type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to an `Args` type with all [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) works except TypeScript is unable to infer from [index access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html); that is, it can infer `A` from a value of type `A`, but it cannot infer `T extends {a: any}` from a value of type `T["a"]`.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#51612](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51612) which would do this, but again, it's not part of the language yet.

There might be some hope for one or both of the most recent two issues mentioned being fixed.  In fact there is a pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#53017](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53017) which implements the last one, but I don't know if it will be merged.  (A much older pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#20126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126) also implemented it, but it was abandoned.)

But until then you will need to use workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you can go about it with classes, I usually just use `type` and you can do this:

```
type Tuple3<a,b,c> = [a,b,c]

const t3: Tuple3<number, string, string> = [3, 'apple', 'banana']

type NamedTuple2<a,b> = Tuple3<string,a,b>

const namedT2: NamedTuple2<number, string> = ['fruites', 2,...
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAzAHgIYBoBGWDGAfFALxQDa2e+AugFB34D2AdgM7BTAoBcsCydCzgBbHBABOWKBwkBLFgHNpshYuJlyKaQHIMYJBB26cGFmYw76dUJCgA5DCIgATeIYBMmXBv6H0qkpYVIQMzOyc5s5uHnyO0e7IXsJikirA8kq+5DoAZhJwcsAQbMZQHrpgChD6hlZAA)